# Unable to get the deserialized object to lightning controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, json

**Component:**

```
<aura:component controller="LightningController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global"  >
<aura:attribute name="purposes" type="ApexDataContainer" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />

    data: {!v.purposes}
</aura:component>
```

**Controller:**

```
    ({
        doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
            var getdata = component.get("c.JsonGetValue");
            getdata.setCallback(this, function(response){      
                var state = response.getState();
                if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                    var result = response.getReturnValue();
                    console.log('1'+JSON.stringify(result));
                    console.log('2'+result['purposes']);
component.set("v.purposes",response.getReturnValue());
                }
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(getdata);      
        }
    })
```

**APEX:**

```
public class LightningController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static ApexDataContainer JsonGetValue() {
        ApexDataContainer c1 = new ApexDataContainer();
    System.debug('hello');
        String json1=           '{'+
        ''+
        '    "purposes": ['+
        ''+
        '        {'+
        ''+
        '            "purpose": "service-improvement",'+
        ''+
        '            "legalGround": "ic",'+
        ''+
        '            "status": "not_answered",'+
        ''+
        '            "description": ['+
        ''+
        '                {'+
        ''+
        '                    "language": "sv-EN",'+
        ''+
        '                    "text": "Service data structure"'+
        ''+
        '                }'+
        ''+
        '            ],'+
        ''+
        '            "version": "1.0.0",'+
        ''+
        '            "dataIds": []'+
        ''+
        '        }'+
        '    ]'+
        ''+
        '}';       
        c1 = (ApexDataContainer)JSON.deserialize(json1,ApexDataContainer.class);

        system.debug('wrapper'+c1.purposes.size());
        return c1;
    }
}
```

In apex debug log, I see that the json object has been successfully parsed, while in a lightning controller, I dont get the value in response.getreturnvalue for this apex method (JsonGetValue) in the console.log itself

I saw in a couple of blogs that we can pass an object from APEX and refer in lightning controller and component

Can someone help me understand why I am not getting the object in the lightning controller console log

Comment: If you have the JSON then you can directly return it.

Comment: the string that i passed over there will be received from an integration callout . the string is the sample response so I have to deserialize as per my class and then i have to show the values in the lightning component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any object member that you return to Lightning needs to be `@AuraEnabled`.

This means that in your ApexDataContainer class, you need to add this annotation to all variables.

Eg:

```
public class ApexDataContainer {
    @AuraEnabled
    public PurposesContainer[] purposes {get;set;}
}


public class PurposesContainer {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String purpose {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String legalGround {get;set;}
    ///etc etc
}
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do, but that string that you defined seems to be a difficult way to do it!

Comment: I will add the aura annotation and see if that works. But yes to answer your question about the string, the string that i passed over there will be received from an integration callout . the string is the sample response so I have to deserialize as per my class and then i have to show the values in the lightning component

Answer (score 0):

Caspar Harmer is correct, any member that you want to be visible to the Aura view components will need @AuraEnabled keyword. Once you do that you will get the Object in the Controller JS. Then you can use native JavaScript method `JSON.parse` to get the details.

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var getdata = component.get("c.JsonGetValue");
        getdata.setCallback(this, function(response){      
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === 'SUCCESS'){
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                var rootObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));
                var purposesObjArray = rootObj.purposes;
                var purposesObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purposesObjArray[0]));
                console.log("purpose : "+purposesObj.purpose);
                console.log("legalGround : "+purposesObj.legalGround);
                console.log("status : "+purposesObj.status);
                var descriptionObj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(purposesObj.description[0]));
                console.log("description-language : "+descriptionObj.language);
                console.log("description-text : "+descriptionObj.text);
                console.log("version : "+purposesObj.version);
                component.set("v.purposes",JSON.stringify(purposesObj));
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(getdata);      
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks Yes, thats true i missed adding @auraenabled which makes me getting null value in the component. Secondly, I think since I am already returning an object type back to the Js controller so I don't need to stringify and then parse (JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));), I will be able to directly  access those values in the controller